# Apache Start .sh script

Tags: apache

```
#!/bin/bash
# Apache Process Monitor
# Restart Apache Web Server When It Goes Down
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) 2003 nixCraft project <http://cyberciti.biz/fb/>
# This script is licensed under GNU GPL version 2.0 or above
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This script is part of nixCraft shell script collection (NSSC)
# Visit http://bash.cyberciti.biz/ for more information.
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# RHEL / CentOS / Fedora Linux restart command
RESTART="/sbin/service httpd restart" 
# uncomment if you are using Debian / Ubuntu Linux
#RESTART="/etc/init.d/apache2 restart" 
#path to pgrep command
PGREP="pgrep"
# Httpd daemon name,
# Under RHEL/CentOS/Fedora it is httpd
# Under Debian 4.x it is apache2
HTTPD="httpd"
# find httpd pid
$PGREP ${HTTPD}
if [ $? -ne 0 ] # if apache not running
then
# restart apache
$RESTART
fi
exit
```

this is my script. when i run it i get 
: command not foundin/apache_start.sh: line 12: 
: command not foundin/apache_start.sh: line 22: pgrep
/usr/local/apache/bin/apache_start.sh: line 29: syntax error: unexpected end of file

what mistake i made. i would be very happy if anybody answer me.

Comment: add more tags to your post, like bash and shell scripting. it will help you get answers faster and better.

Comment: it is better to ask this question on superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

dude, I ran your script and it works fine except the $PGREP ${HTTPD} part, if you want to get a pid why don't you use "pidof" command, and I think in your if statement you are testing the return value of grep, not httpd command(not sure).
 anyway did you edit this script in word document or in an editor, cause you know this may add some invisible characters to your code.
to debug it, I suggest that you comment out rest of your code where you get the first error and see figure out the solution to that specific error.

Comment: no, i used notepad. but not worked. However, when i created same file using vi command and set appropriate permission it is working. Thanks a lot